# Visual Studio for .NET Core doesn't copy file to output while test runner does

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mstest, .net-core

I have specified `buildOptions` to copy settings file to output:

```
  "buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput": { "includeFiles": [ "appsettings.json" ] }
  },
```

If I build a project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, file is not copied to output. But if I launch `dotnet test` with Mstest test runner, file is copied. How is this possible? Do they run different kinds of builds?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is close to its final release. Use that for the latest .NET Core support.